# What is a word or phrase to describe a new article that's using outdated sources?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I am reading an article that is new, but it's citing completely outdated sources of information. Granted, without knowledge in the field, it would be hard to detect these inaccuracies.

I want to say, "This article is **outdated,**" but that could be misconstrued to mean it's an old article with old information. What is the best, most succinct way to describe the situation without implying that the article itself is old?

Comment: I think the common phrasing is "based on outdated information".

Comment: A 2000-and-late article. ;)

Comment: It could be called *stale*.

Comment: +1 for @DanBron. variant: "based on obsolete information".

Comment: The article uses outdated information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say,

> The article is not up-to-date.

This doesn't have the problem we see with the other version ("the article is outdated").  This version only means one thing.

Here is an example of an author using this phrase:

> "**Cite recent literature.**  If you are writing in the social sciences and many of your citations are more than three to five years old, the reviewers may state that the *article is not up-to-date*."

*("Writing Your Journal Article in 12 Weeks" by Wendy Laura Belcher*, available in [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=Bis8p2ejEqIC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22the%20article%20is%20not%20up%20to%20date%22&source=bl&ots=Cb8Dxx1KzP&sig=dO3C8u4MMXTriAJqzwxkXlCkFhQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju4efJ2N7QAhWHdSYKHV72ASoQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22the%20article%20is%20not%20up%20to%20date%22&f=false)).

Comment: This is the best answer to describe the article itself using a single word (up-to-date). I also like Dan Bron's suggestion, "based on outdated information," which is in a comment on the OP.

Comment: @bvpx - Glad it's helpful.  I sort of cheated, though, because it's actually a two-word phrase -- "not up-to-date."